# Page Index Changed. GridView data showing is lost

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, page-index-changed

I have a GridView that shows particular data list or reports when clicking Generate button.

[GridView Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCKru.png)

When I'm moving to the next page of the GridView or when I click the next page, the GridView binding becomes empty and it shows no GridView list.

[Page Index Changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLmsG.png)

Here's my code in `.aspx`

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"
    runat="server"
    CellPadding="4"
    HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
    ForeColor="#333333"
    GridLines="None"
    CssClass="mGrid"
    PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
    RowStyle-CssClass="row"
    AllowSorting="True"
    AllowPaging="True"
    PageSize="25" Visible="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
    EnableViewState="false">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        No record found.
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here's my code for `Page_Load`

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            userid = IIf(SessionHandler.UserID = "", User.Identity.Name.ToUpper, SessionHandler.UserID)

            V3Substance.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "javascript:if (this.value=='Substance Cas Number') { this.value = ''; }")
            V3Substance.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:if (this.value=='') { this.value = 'Substance Cas Number'; }")

            If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
                V1Division.DataSource = GetDivision()
                V1Division.DataBind()

                V1BR.Items.Clear()
                V1BR.DataSource = GetBusinessRule(V1Division.Text)
                V1BR.DataBind()

                MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0
                Panel1.DefaultButton = "V1Generate"
            End If
        End Sub
```

Here's my code for `GridView1_PageIndexChanging`

```
Protected Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridView1.PageIndexChanging
    Dim dt As DataTable = TryCast(GridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
    GridView1.DataSource = SortTable(dt)

    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

And here's my code for `BindGridView`

```
 Private Sub BindGridview(ByVal query As String, ByVal countquery As String)
            ViewState.Add("Query", query)
            ViewState.Add("CountQuery", countquery)

            Dim count As Integer = 0

            If Description.Text = "1" Then
                ValidateFamily(query)
            Else
                DataSource = dbHelper.GetRecordDT(query)
            End If

            count = DataSource.Rows.Count

            'GridView1.DataSource = Nothing
            'GridView1.DataBind()
            'GridView1.PageIndex = 0

            GridView1.DataSource = DataSource
            GridView1.Visible = True
            GridView1.DataBind()

            ExportToExcel.Visible = IIf(count < 1, False, True)
            Panel1.Visible = IIf(count < 1, False, True)
            SetTotalResult(count)
        End Sub
```

I hope you can help me with this. I can't seem to know what could be the problem. I tried different approach to this and find a solutions from the internet but it didn't help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using

```
GridView1.DataSource = DataSource
```

It's unclear from your snippet what `DataSource` is, but you use it in the `BindGridview` method also.

Start using different names for variables, naming them exactly as properties is very confusing and will lead to errors.

**Update**

```
Dim source As SqlDataSource

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)       
    source = New SqlDataSource
    source.ID = "mySource"
    source.SelectCommand = "select * from table"
    source.ConnectionString = connStr

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        GridView1.DataSource = source
        GridView1.DataBind
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
    GridView1.DataSource = source
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    GridView1.DataBind
End Sub
```

Comment: so I need to put GridView1.DataSource = DataSource in Page_Load and GridView1_PageIndexChanging?? @VDWWD